# why my audio sound is not playing in my arduino code but if i play it separately it started working good

Tags: arduino, interrupt, arduino-c++

I am trying to set the timer after which the audio will automatically played once but it is not playing anything just a noise but when i run the audio program separately it work perfectly good

This is my code please help me out where i am doing wrong.

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <TMRpcm.h>
#include <SPI.h>

int timer1_counter;
#define SD_ChipSelectPin 4
TMRpcm tmrpcm;

unsigned long time_now = 0;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
const byte ledPin = 13;

const byte interruptPin1 = 2;
const byte interruptPin2 = 3;
int counter2 = 0;

volatile byte state = LOW;
int count = 0;

int limit = 0;
bool TimerFlag = false;
int deviceTime = 0;

int set = 5;
bool soundplayflag = false;

void setup() 
{
    lcd.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(interruptPin1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(interruptPin2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(set, INPUT_PULLUP);

    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("Please Select:");

    noInterrupts();           // disable all interrupts

    TCCR1A = 0;

    TCCR1B = 0;

    TCNT1  = 0;

    OCR1A = 31250;            // compare match register 16MHz/256/2Hz

    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12);   // CTC mode

    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12);    // 256 prescaler 

    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A);  // enable timer compare interrupt

    interrupts();             // enable all interrupts
    // initialize timer1 
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)          // timer compare interrupt service routine
{
    if (soundplayflag == true)
    {
        counter2 = counter2+1;
        Serial.println(counter2/2);
    }
}

void loop() 
{
    //unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    int up = digitalRead(interruptPin1);
    int down = digitalRead(interruptPin2);
    int setbutton = digitalRead(set);

    delay(230);

    if (up == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("Entering up");
        count++;
        if (count >= 0) {
            lcdprint(count);    
        }

    }
    else if (down == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("Entering down");
        count--;
        if (count >= 0) {
            lcdprint(count);
        }

    }
    else if (setbutton == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("Entering set");
        soundplayflag=true;
        deviceTime = count;
    }

    if (deviceTime > 0)
    {
        if (deviceTime == counter2)
        {
            soundplayflag=false;
            Serial.println("Hello world");
            PlaySound();
            counter2 = 0;
        }
    }
}

int lcdprint(int a)
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(1,0);
    lcd.print("Please Select:");

    lcd.setCursor (7,1);
    lcd.print(a);
    Serial.println(a);

    lcd.setCursor (10,1);
    lcd.print("Min");
}// end of lcdprint(int a)


void PlaySound()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tmrpcm.setVolume(5);
        tmrpcm.play("3.wav");
        delay(1000);
    }// end of for loop
}// end of void PlaySound()
```

my expected output is it should play the sound when i set the time

Comment: Serial.println(counter2/2) inside an ISR is a terrible idea.  You have a division and a very time-consuming serial port operation in there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [TMRpcm uses Timer1](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki), which conflicts with your `TIMER1_COMPA_vect`. That would explain why it's working if you run nothing else.

Maybe try to use [`#define USE_TIMER2`](https://github.com/TMRh20/TMRpcm/wiki/Advanced-Features)?